# HTML Encoding of request parameters

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, urlencode

My application is a Spring MVC application, does not use annotations (its quite an old application though it uses spring 3.1.1).

I have a JSP page that can be invoked via a tool like curl or directly from the web browser URL. The URL accepts a request parameter called location

```
http://localhost:8080/testdomain/registeruser.do?mylocation=fr
```

On invoking the above url, I call an implementation of SimpleFormController that reads the request parameter "mylocation"

How do I html encode the request parameter "mylocation". Before reading the parameter from the request [request.getParameter("mylocation")] in my controller, would is suffice if I call HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(request.getParameter("mylocation"))

Please note there is no form backing the input parameter for mylocation, as outlined earlier I could call this from a command line tool or browser URL.

Comment: Why do you want to encode anything? Do you get correct values for mylocation parameter? You usually don't need to escape/unescape anything if this is only alphanumeric value.

Comment: There could be a threat of XSS, one can pass scripts with malicious intent. I am given to understand HTML encoding will convert script special chars to its encoded form.

Comment: What are you doing with that parameter? If you are outputting the data inside a js variable HTML Escaping won't be enough. However if you only have a single untrusted param you can verifiy it in a simpler way. For example checking if myLocation's value exists in a Enum type before generate the output: MyAllowedLocations.valueOf(myLocation);

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things:

1) URL encoding/decoding - it is only to allow passing GET parameters to the server. Encoding is needed because server need to escape some special characters "?" , "&" in query string.
It is usually handled by web server like Tomcat.

2) And to prevent XSS you can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer). It is only needed if you will present value from parameter on the web page.

Some frameworks, like JSF can prevent XSS automatically. They can escape HTML when it is displayed on the web page.

Comment: Is URL Encoding same as HTML Encoding? Secondly, I don't agree that XSS is required only if the value from the parameter is going to be shown on the web page. There can be scenarios, such as using a iframe or innerHTML that could get bound with the request parameter and cause XSS attacks. Thanks for the reference to JSoup, I will look into it further.

Comment: No, to prevent XSS you need only HTML encoding. Scripts will not be executed in the browser address bar, so you don't need to encode/decode URL to prevent XSS.

Comment: Why can I not pass script tag (java script tag) as a request parameter from browser url or say a curl command?. What if this script is not encoded, and is able to execute itself internally within the code. It does not have to be rendered on the page to be executed. Also please refer this link , it has some interesting examples, https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting#Sample_vulnerability

Comment: It needs to be rendered in the browser to be executed. You can escape/unescape Script, you don't encode/decode it to prevent XSS. You can encode/decode URL and this has nothing to do with XSS. If a script (Bash, SQL) is send to the server to do some harm it is different type of attack.